# Standard Object Tab not displayed in New User Account

Tags: customer-portal, standard-objects

I have Developer Account and i have created another 2 users...When i logged in as a another user i have no option for the Standard Object tab..Ex:- Account,Contact,Opportunity,etc...

So how can i insert Account data in the new user Account Objects?

Here anything may i missed any concept at the time of creating new user?

So Please Help me to add Standard Object tab into the new User Account..

thanks in Advanced For your Answere.....

Comment: Sir i use Developer Account(free developer Account) for my own used.When i open new user account there is only one custom object tab is there when i opened that custom tab then one message is there .."Insufficient Privileges"

Comment: Please Any one Help me....Same problem arise when logged in as a customer portal....

Answer (score 1):

Do you use standard user profile?
Those profile by default don't have access to any custom objects beside those defined in package as accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Developer Edition comes with two full Salesforce licenses which provide access to all of the standard objects such as account, opportunity etc.

If you have created three users then at least one of these will not be able to access some standard objects, depending on the license you chose when you created the user.

Salesforce platform licenses can use accounts and contacts, but none of the other standard objects like opportunities and leads.  Other licenses are more restrictive.

To find out the capabilities of the user license that you have chosen, navigate to Setup -> Manage Users -> Users, click through the record for the user in question and find the license on the top right:

[image]

and then check the license capabilities at:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_available.htm&language=en_US

There may also be restrictions for the profile that you have selected for the user - to check this, click the Profile field link (below the User License in the screen shot) and check the permissions for the object(s) you wish to access. Note that the profile cannot override the license restrictions, so if a license doesn't provide access to an sobject, it won't appear in the profile.

If you are a Salesforce partner you can sign up for a partner developer edition which comes with more licenses.

Answer (score 0):

please check the sercuity setting, maybe another user don't have access to Accout Object.

Comment: Thanks for answer sir,but i have two users and one is admin,and now i make a thired user but all of three have no standard object tab,only one custom object tab is there and when i opened it,"Insufficient Privileges"....so what can i do next....

Comment: maybe this document would be help http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/adg_securing_data_control_access_objects.htm